# Creating a custom button to be able to grab the data from an Outlook email and move that data to an Oracle Table

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, outlook-restapi

I am looking to see if somebody can guide me or direct me to the right path. I need to develop a custom button in Outlook 2013 where the user can extract the data (From, To, Body and attachment) to an Oracle table.
I found VSTO using C# could help me do this. I am wondering if this is the right way or if there is a better way?
I am capable to write C# and Python. However, I do not know if using Python I will be able to create a custom button in Outlook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need to develop a COM add-in where you can create a custom UI for your needs and do the required actions. See [Walkthrough: Create your first VSTO Add-in for Outlook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/walkthrough-creating-your-first-vsto-add-in-for-outlook?view=vs-2019) for getting started quickly.

VSTO provides two main ways for customizing the Fluent UI in Office applications:

- [Walkthrough: Create a custom tab by using Ribbon XML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/walkthrough-creating-a-custom-tab-by-using-ribbon-xml?view=vs-2019)
- [Walkthrough: Create a custom tab by using the Ribbon Designer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/walkthrough-creating-a-custom-tab-by-using-the-ribbon-designer?view=vs-2019)

I'd suggest starting from the Ribbon Designer first. If required, you may export your designed UI into an XML file and continue working on features that the designer doesn't support.